What is the definition of a "tail" for normal or skewed distribution
I am trying to find the definition of a tail of a distribution(positive or negative) graph, but I can't seem to find it. Different sources(and pictures) seem to suggest different "definitions" of it.
source 1(under "What is a “Tail”?"), https://www.statisticshowto.com/upper-tail-and-lower-tail/

suggests just the edges

source 2(under "Right Skewed Distribution Histogram"), https://www.ztable.net/skewed-distribution/

from median to the furthest point

source 3(under "Introduction"), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#cite_note-cnx.org-1

more of a general deviation of a symmetric center.

I belive that "tail" used as suggested in source 3, which is my second option below:
What is the tail of a distribution is it(for the left tail in this case):

Median to minimum, or Quartile 1 to minimum?
(suggested by source 3)is it more of general idea of the tapering off of the graph, with no clearly definded definition?

I know about the tail ends, but I would like to be 100% certain about the "definition" of the "full" tail.

Not sure what you are after.  As you have noticed, people use "tail" informally.  Typically, theyy mean to suggest that standard distributions do a poor job at estimating the probability of events far from the mean.  Not sure there's any point to a precise definition.  Of course, for specific distributions one can look at explicit measurements.

@lulu, thanks for your reply. Its just something I wanted to know like if there was a actual definitaion like: "the tail is between the points a and b".

Having worked with the notion for decades, I think I can confidently state that there is no universally accepted definition.  In context, risk management say, one makes up a measure that fits conditions appropriately.
